# Kubernetes equivalent of 'docker run -it'

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I have one docker image and I am using following command to run it.

```
docker run -it -p 1976:1976 --name demo demo.docker.cloud.com/demo/runtime:latest
```

I want to run the same in Kubernetes. This is my current yaml file.

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-deployment
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: demo
        image: demo.docker.cloud.com/demo/runtime:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1976
        imagePullPolicy: Never
```

This yaml file covers everything except flag "-it". I am not able to find its Kubernetes equivalent. Please help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: `--interactive` and `--tty`. what's your use case?

Comment: My guess is they want to attach a shell into the running container in Kubernettes...

Comment: Will these flags --interactive and --tty will also be same in Kubernetes? How do I put them in yaml file?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to connect a shell to your running container.  Following the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/ - You would need the following commands.  To `apply` your above configuration:

Create the pod: `kubectl apply -f ./demo-deployment.yaml`

Verify the Container is running: `kubectl get pod demo-deployment`

Get a shell to the running Container: `kubectl exec -it demo-deployment -- /bin/bash`

Comment: There is one problem here that this article talks about getting a shell after successful deployment. But in my case, We need shell to install the product itself contains by image file.

Comment: @AkashKumar Installation should be done before you get to kubernetes during the image build phase, usually via a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). The container image you supply to k8s should be ready to run without interaction.

Comment: @Matt Yes that would have been the best case but due to certain restrictions, I can't change the image file or Dockerfile while creating the image.

Comment: @AkashKumar Can you create a `Dockerfile` `FROM demo.docker.cloud.com/demo/runtime:latest` and push the new image to your repo? Manually installing something (in every pod) every time kubernetes needs to reschedule a pod is not going to a fun experience!

Comment: @Matt This can be one option, but then only I would be able to use this. Other people won't be preferring getting it from my repo rather than official one. I am forced to try something with Kubernetes yaml file, even if it will be pain later.

Comment: If you need to manually 'build' your container every time you deploy, then you aren't going to be able to reap the majority of the benefits that k8s gives you - you won't be able to scale your services... what about when a service gets rescheduled?  It won't have the right software installed on it... etc.

Comment: It is really common to use something like Nexus or Artifactory, configure it to be a local site cache for a remote docker repo (like docker hub), and also host your own internal containers.  You also could pay docker for private repos on docker hub, or use a service like quay.io

Comment: Also, to address your probable 'seperation of concerns' side - This is where people usually run multiple clusters - you have your dev/CI cluster that developers can publish to and deploy to, and you 'promote' your containers after they have been successfully vetted/verified for use in your 'ops' or 'production' cluster.

Comment: @Cinderhaze Yes I have created a new image by making the previous image interactive and tested currently locally and it works fine. Along with that I also have found another way to run this from command line without using yaml file:  'kubectl run -it demo --image=demo.docker.cloud.com/demo/runtime:latest --image-pull-policy=Never --port=1976'

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Container definition in the API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#container-v1-core), the equivalent options are `stdin: true` and `tty: true`.

(None of the applications I work on have ever needed this; the documentation for `stdin:` talks about "reads from stdin in the container" and the typical sort of server-type processes you'd run in a Deployment don't read from stdin at all.)

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl run` is the close match to `docker run` based on the requested scenario.

Some examples from Kubernetes documentation and it's purpose :

```sh
kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox -- sh  # Run pod as interactive shell
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx -n 
mynamespace                                         # Run pod nginx in a specific namespace
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx                     # Run pod nginx and write its spec into a file called pod.yaml
--dry-run=client -o yaml > pod.yaml
```